# Wearables Rotate Screen Based on Orientation

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, autorotate

For Android Wear devices it is possible to enable auto rotation of the screen based on the device orientation? For instance, if I hold my hand straight up in the air in front of me, palm out, the watch face will be sideways and all the text will be hard to read.

Is there an auto-rotate feature like on handheld android devices, where the screen orientation will match gravity?

I would really love to enable this in my app.

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer to this; If I set `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` in the activity definition (in the manifest), this is completely ignored. If I change the themes they seem to have no effect either.

That said, it IS possible to manually change the orientation if necessary. I personally don't like this solution, so if someone has a better one please do contribute one. (Side note: I realize it makes sense for Wear applications to not auto-orient, but this has been requested by my client so it needs be implemented one way or another.)

This code is not perfect but it should get you started if you need it:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // .. other code ..
    startRotationListening();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // .. other code ..
    stopRotationListening();
}

protected void startRotationListening() {
    try {
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR), SENSOR_DELAY);
        listeningToRotation = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Rotation hardware? What hardware?", e);
    }
}

protected void stopRotationListening() {
    if (listeningToRotation) {
        try {
            SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            listeningToRotation = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Rotation hardware? What hardware?", e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    //if (event.sensor == rotationSensor) {
        if (event.values.length > 4) {
            float[] truncatedRotationVectors = new float[4];
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, truncatedRotationVectors, 0, 4);
            onRotationChange(truncatedRotationVectors);
        }
    //}
}

protected void onRotationChange(float[] vectors) {
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9], adjustedMatrix = new float[9], orientation = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, vectors);
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, adjustedMatrix);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedMatrix, orientation);

    float pitch = orientation[1] * RADS_TO_DEGS, roll = orientation[2] * RADS_TO_DEGS;

    String strOrientation = null;
    int screenOrientation = -1;
    if (pitch <= -80 && pitch >= -100) {
        // Too flat (face up), ignore orientation
        strOrientation = "FLAT_UP";
    } else if (pitch >= 80 && pitch <= 100) {
        // Too flat (face down), ignore orientation
        strOrientation = "FLAT_DN";
    }

    if (strOrientation == null) {
        if (roll >= -10 && roll <= 10) {
            screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            strOrientation = "UPRIGHT";
        } else if (roll <= -80 && roll >= -110) {
            screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
            strOrientation = "ONRIGHT";
        } else if (roll >= 170 || roll <= -170) {
            screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
            strOrientation = "TOPSIDE";
        } else if (roll >= 80 && roll <= 100) {
            screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            strOrientation = " ONLEFT";
        } else {
            strOrientation = "  ???  ";
        }
    }

    if (screenOrientation != -1) {
        setRequestedOrientation(screenOrientation);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s Pitch: %f, roll: %f", strOrientation, pitch, roll));
}
```